# How to start subequations with a known number?

Tags: subequations

I want my subequations starting with number (9u).

How can I do this?

Comment: Why u? And why 9? Can you please give some more context?

Comment: I have a long list of subequations which cannot fit  into a single page. The first part of subequations  ends with (9t). I am trying to write the second part at second page as new subequations  starting with (9u).

Comment: There is no restriction on `subequations`: it can span several pages. You've possibly asked the wrong question: maybe you need to split a long `align` or similar environment across pages.

Comment: Unfortunately, the IEEE template I use does not allow this.

Comment: Doesn't allow what? Does it prohibit `\displaybreak`?

Comment: \begin{figure*}
\begin{subequations}
{
....
}
\end{subequations}
\end{figure*}  .I have to use figure{*} which does allows\displaybreak. but does not make any split!

Comment: thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would do it, but here it is.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{storesubequations}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
y
\end{equation}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
a&=b \\
c&=d
\end{align}%
\setcounter{storesubequations}{\value{equation}}%
\end{subequations}

\addtocounter{equation}{-1}
\begin{subequations}\setcounter{equation}{\value{storesubequations}}
\begin{align}
e&=f \\
g&=h
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{equation}
y
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]